# how to tail -f on multiple files with a script?

Tags: unix, ksh

I am trying to tail multiple files in a ksh. I have the following script:

test.sh

```
#!/bin/ksh

for file in "$@"
do
        # show tails of each in background.
        tail -f $file>out.txt
        echo "\n"
done
```

It is only reading the first file argument I provide to the script. Not reading the other files as the argument to the script.

When I do this:

```
./test.sh /var/adm/messages /var/adm/logs
```

it is only reading the /var/adm/messages not the logs. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong

Comment: Your comment says "show tails in background" but the redirection means you will not see any output -- it will be captured in the file. But as K4timini points out, you should only be seeing the `logs` file (not `messages`) in your output because of using `>` instead of `>>` Also, probably use quotes around `"$file"` to be safe.

Comment: Do you need the `-f` option? That "follows" the file as it grows and won't return from the first call until it's interrupted with ctrl-C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use double ">>" syntax to redirect the stream at the end of your output file. 
A simple ">" redirection will write the stream at the beginning of the file and consequently it will remove the previous content.

So try :

```
#!/bin/ksh

for file in "$@"
do
        # show tails of each in background.
        tail -f $file >> out.txt & # Don't forget to add the last character
done
```

EDIT : If you want to use multi tail it's not installed by default. On Debian or Ubuntu you can use apt-get install multi tail.

Comment: This is not working in my system. Are you sure this works perfectly? I can only see o/p of first file appended everytime

Comment: If you want to write the output stream in a file for each input file you have to use a >> operand to write at the end of the file.
However if you only want to display it in a Terminal you need to remove the "> out.txt" to redirect the stream in the console.

>> & > are two operands to redirect a stream.

Comment: @K4timini, I tried that it is only capturing the first files' tail -f nto the second.

Comment: Add a "&" operand at the end of the line. (I edited my previous post). It works well for me on Mac OSX and Debian Server.

Please mark resolved if it's ok for you !

Comment: @K4timini, one other quick question. If I wanted to include the hostname and file name into the out.txt file next to each entry, how would I do that?

Comment: You can use the 'hostname' command to get the host name.
So : hostname >> out.txt before the loop.
If you want to add the file name for each file you have to add : echo "$file" >> out.txt in the loop (before the tail for example)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50805/discussion-between-k4timini-and-user1471980)

Comment: @K4timini, yes it kind of works but I need to have the hostname and the file name right next to the tail -f output (in the same line).

Comment: @K4timini, chat is not allowed on my browser.